# Alphabet Regex Pattern?

Tags: c#, regex

If I have a letter say "w" and I want to it to match only against a few characters in the alphabet for example " the letter a, d and then h to q and w only. How can I achieve this?

All I have so far is : ^[h-qH-Q]+$

I assume its pretty easy but i'm not really a regex expert...

Comment: regex is probably overkill/the wrong tool for this

Comment: Does that letter, say "w", have to be alone in the line?

Comment: the letter that will be passed into the regex could be any letter it just needs to match a, d then between h or q or w. If c was to be passed in then it wouldn't match. That's kind of what I meant.

Comment: regex101.com that is a good site to just play around with regexes, it tells you what they are doing too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^[aAdDh-qH-QwW]$
```

It will only match single letters on the input line.

Hoping this is what you mean.